# Error while controling visibility with setVisible method

Tags: java, awt

While controlling the visibility of some components through a button, I am getting stackoverflow error.

I am setting `setVisible(true)` for some components based on the click of a button with `actionperformed()` method.

I am getting stackoverflow error on line 25 and 55.

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Expanse extends Frame {

    Label l1, l2;
    Button b1, b2, b3;
    Frame f1;
    TextField tf1, tf2;

    Expanse() {
        l1 = new Label("welcome user");
        Font font1 = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 25);
        Font font2 = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 18);
        l1.setFont(font1);
        addWindowListener(new myWindowAdapter());
        l1.setBounds(100, 25, 300, 50);
        add(l1);
        l2 = new Label("please click any button from below");
        l2.setBounds(75, 100, 500, 50);
        l2.setFont(font2);
        add(l2);
        b1 = new Button("add data");
        b1.setBounds(70, 175, 100, 50);
        add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener(new addListener());
        b2 = new Button("retrive data");
        b2.setBounds(275, 175, 100, 50);
        add(b2);
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
        tf1 = new TextField("enter amount");
        tf2 = new TextField("enter reason");
        tf1.setBounds(70, 260, 150, 30);
        add(tf1);
        tf2.setBounds(70, 320, 150, 30);
        add(tf2);
        b3 = new Button("write");
        b3.setBounds(100, 380, 80, 35);
        add(b3);
        tf1.setVisible(false);
        tf2.setVisible(false);
        b3.setVisible(false);
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        Expanse e1 = new Expanse();
    }
}

class myWindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter {

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class addListener extends Expanse implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        tf1.setVisible(true);
        tf2.setVisible(true);
        b3.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no [tag:javafx]. Your listener `extends Expanse`, calling the `Expanse` constructor recursively when instantiated within the `Expanse` constructor.

Comment: Possible [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+constructor+recursive+extends+stackoverflow).

Comment: 1) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). ..

Comment: .. 3) *"controling visibility"* Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) for the component(s) of relevance, as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). In this case, the cards would be a) The component. b) A blank panel.

Answer (score 2):

Within `Expanse` constructor you have: 
`b1.addActionListener(new addListener());` 
which constructs an `addListener` object. <sup>1</sup>
`addListener` extends `Expanse` so you are creating another `Expanse` object withing the `Expanse` constructor. 
[As pointed out by trashgod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58988797/error-while-controling-visibility-with-setvisible-method#comment104232817_58988797) this is an endless process which causes the `stackoverflow`.
The cure is simple: there is no reason for `addListener` to extend `Expanse`.

```
class addListener implements ActionListener {...}
```

I assume the `extends Expanse` was added to gain access to `tf1` and other class variables, but it is not the way to do it. 
Alternatively simply have `addListener` class, an inner class in `Expanse`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Side note: see [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/)